# How block scroll and height of body before slideUp() of element and remove css after slideDown() of new element ? - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I assure you that I'm going crazy.
I've tried hundreds of changes but I can not solve this problem.

In practice I have a page with 3 tabs but only one tab can be displayed at a time.
If you click on the button, to view the new tab, the old one will be a `slideUp` and after that the new tab will appear with a `slideDown`.

The problem is that the tabs have different heights, so when a tab disappears, for a few moments, the window will have a different height and an automatic scroll will occur.

I want to avoid this scroll but I do not know how ...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(document).scrollTop(30);

   //se viene cliccato un altro pulsante "SCHEDA"
   $('#button-scheda-mappa, #button-scheda-vulcani, #button-scheda-storici').on('click', function() {
     var mostra_scheda = ($(this).attr('id')).substr(7);

     $('#scheda-mappa, #scheda-vulcani, #scheda-storici').not('#' + mostra_scheda).slideUp(800); ////chiudo le altre voci aperte e le "pulisco" (eccetto quella appena cliccata)
     $('#' + mostra_scheda).delay(500).slideDown(800); //mostro la tendina del form (che sarebbe l'elemento successivo a quello appena cliccato)

   });
   //
 });
```

```css
#box-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
}

#button-scheda-mappa,
#button-scheda-vulcani,
#button-scheda-storici {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#schede {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#scheda-mappa,
#scheda-vulcani,
#scheda-storici {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: auto;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<div id="box-buttons">
  <div id="button-scheda-mappa">
    1
  </div>
  <div id="button-scheda-vulcani">
    2
  </div>
  <div id="button-scheda-storici">
    3
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="schede">
  <div id="scheda-mappa">
    <div style="height: 3000px">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="scheda-vulcani" style="display:none; width: calc(100% - 2px); height: auto; background-color: #a0a0a0; border: 1px solid #404040; position: relative; top: -1px">
    <div style="height: 300px">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="scheda-storici" style="display:none; width: calc(100% - 2px); height: auto; background-color: #a0a0a0; border: 1px solid #404040; position: relative; top: -1px">
    <div style="height: 100px">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fgt9odc8/

**I strongly recommend looking at the jsfiddle** because the effect of the scroll is not observed here with the snippet.
In the code the page starts with

```
      $(document).scrollTop(30);
```

and when click a new button (to open new tab) the scrollTop position change :(

I hope you can help me and sorry for my english.

Comment: I think this link will help you, check this link and in demo page, demo4 is what you are looking at https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ContentTabs/

Comment: i think your comment can't help me

Comment: in your link there's also a VIRUS !

Answer (score 0):

I solve blocking `scroll` of **body** with `overflow-y: hidden` before slideUp of old tab and removing this css after slideDown of new tab.
Also i saved position of `window` before to change the tab and making a scroll to this (old) position after the new tab is show.

I hope that this answer can help someone...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $(document).scrollTop(30);

      //se viene cliccato un altro pulsante "SCHEDA"
      $('#button-scheda-mappa, #button-scheda-vulcani, #button-scheda-storici').on('click', function() {
        var mostra_scheda = ($(this).attr('id')).substr(7);
        var blocca_scroll= $(window).scrollTop();   //posizione della finestra prima del cambio scheda      
        $('body, html').css('overflow-y','hidden'); //blocco lo scroll del body

        $('#scheda-mappa, #scheda-vulcani, #scheda-storici').not('#' + mostra_scheda).slideUp(800); ////chiudo le altre voci aperte e le "pulisco" (eccetto quella appena cliccata)
        $('#' + mostra_scheda).delay(500).slideDown(800, function(){
            $(window).scrollTop(blocca_scroll);
            $('body, html').removeAttr('style');    //sblocco anche la possibilità di scrollare la pagina
        });); //mostro la tendina del form (che sarebbe l'elemento successivo a quello appena cliccato)

      });
      //
    });
```